# Discord.js display only User

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How do I filter out the bots in this code so that only users are displayed?

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const token = require('./token.json').token
const client = new Discord.Client();

setInterval(async () => {
  let membersCount = client.guilds.cache.map(guild => guild.memberCount).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  await client.user.setPresence({
    activities: [{
      name: `mit ${membersCount} usern`,
      type: ActivityType.Playing
    }],
    status: "online"
  })
}, 1000 * 60 * 10);

client.login(token)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=users) property then using the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Example:

```js
client.users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot).size
```

Full Example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const token = require('./token.json').token
const client = new Discord.Client();

setInterval(async () => {
  let membersCount = client.users.cache.filter(user => !user.bot).size;
  await client.user.setPresence({
    activities: [{
      name: `mit ${membersCount} usern`,
      type: ActivityType.Playing
    }],
    status: "online"
  })
}, 1000 * 60 * 10);

client.login(token)
```